# how to return a std::expect<T, E> from a function where T's move/copy constructor are deleted and has a private constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, private, public

Currently I have this code, which works fine:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <expected>
#include <wayland-server.h>

class Display
{
private:
    struct wl_display *ptr;

public:
    enum class Error
    {
        CannotCreateDisplay,
    };

    Display() = delete;
    Display(struct wl_display *ptr)
        : ptr{ptr}
    {
    }
    Display(const Display &) = delete;
    Display(Display &&) = delete;
    Display &operator=(const Display &) = delete;
    Display &operator=(Display &&) = delete;
    ~Display()
    {
        wl_display_destroy_clients(this->ptr);
        wl_display_destroy(this->ptr);
    }

    static std::expected<Display, Error> create()
    {
        struct wl_display *ptr{wl_display_create()};
        if (ptr == nullptr) {
            return std::unexpected{Error::CannotCreateDisplay};
        }
        return {ptr};
    }
};
```

I would like to make the `Display(struct wl_display *)` constructor private but I can't because otherwise the `create` would complains about not finding any viable constructor to call for `Display`.

One solution I found, is to make a move constructor for `Display` but is there any else solutions for this ?

```cpp
class Display
{
private:
    struct wl_display *ptr;
    Display(struct wl_display *ptr)
        : ptr{ptr}
    {
    }

public:
    enum class Error
    {
        CannotCreateDisplay,
    };

    Display() = delete;
    Display(const Display &) = delete;
    Display(Display &&) = delete;
    Display &operator=(const Display &) = delete;
    Display &operator=(Display &&) = delete;
    ~Display()
    {
        wl_display_destroy_clients(this->ptr);
        wl_display_destroy(this->ptr);
    }

    static std::expected<Display, Error> create()
    {
        struct wl_display *ptr{wl_display_create()};
        if (ptr == nullptr) {
            return std::unexpected{Error::CannotCreateDisplay};
        }
        return {ptr}; // ERROR: can't find any viable constructor
    }
};
```

Comment: [Doc says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) T requirement is only  Destructible so should be possible.

Comment: [Here is MCVE](https://godbolt.org/z/ecb7za95T)

Comment: Can't reproduce; works with clang https://godbolt.org/z/zo8ofGqGT

Comment: @JanSchultke your ctor `Display(struct wl_display *ptr)` is public.

Comment: Workaround to avoid private constructors is [passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/). (same workaround than for `std::make_unique`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you can, by making use of the monadic operations of the `std::expected`. The same method can be applied to `std::optional`.

Instead of

```
return {ptr};
```

You can detour via another `std::expected`, and transform the value in-place (credit to @Artyer for making it more succinct):

```
return std::expected<void, Error>{}.transform(
    [&] {
        return Display{ptr};
    }
);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/x4aoWsTeT

---

Here is how it works. Without the detour, you have to choose between constructing `Display` directly inside `std::expected`, or constructing `Display` outside and move it.

The former requires invoking the private constructor directly inside the constructor of `std::expected`. Since `std::expected` is not a friend, this is doomed to fail.

The latter only works if `Display` is movable. This is exactly what OP wants to avoid.

With the detour, we are providing a (sort of public) callback function which calls the private constructor in a context that it is allowed. This is similar to the passkey idiom mentioned in the comments: both provide a public construction function that has very limited access. In the passkey idiom, the access is protected by a struct that serves as an authorization token; In this method, the access is protected naturally by scope, as the lambda is a local variable.

Comment: What does this rely on to work?

Comment: @alagner Added some explanation.

Comment: OK I get it now (I think). `as the lambda is a local variable` local to the static factory, that has access to the private constructor. OK that's brilliant. Thanks :)

Comment: Or also: `std::expected<void, Error>{}.transform([&]{ return Display{ ptr }; });`

Comment: @Artyer Advice taken.